# Maximum of Comments on Facebook Events

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-comments

Is there a limit of Facebook Comments on an Event to display?

I think we reach the maximum but I cannot validate this feeling whit official documentation.
The result is that all comment are close for my event on Facebook.

Comment: Jow much comments you got?